# How to use VMWare VIX api's readVariable to retrieve environment variable from guest machine

Tags: environment-variables, vmware

I want to get the value of an environment variable from in a guest VM. VMWare VIX api claims to have this functionality built into their API

for `readVariable` the help reads:

```
Reads a variable from the virtual machine state or guest.
You can get eitherruntime configuration in the .vmx file,
or environment variables in the guest operating system.
The latter requires a valid guest login.
<path to .vmx file>
[ runtimeConfig |
guestEnv ]
<variable name>
```

For example, get the user profile:

```
vmrun -gu myusername -gp myfakepassword readVariable "C:\VMWare-VMs\myusername\myusername-XPSP3-3.vmx" guestEnv %USERPROFILE%
```

but...where does the value of the variable go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`USERPROFILE`, not `%USERPROFILE%`, works

Comment: Only seems to work for User variables, not System variables. :-(